# Comment flagging - condition where "please select a reason" warning appears but flag reason dialog does not

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging, comments

I happened to be flagging two comments as obsolete (on [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30284/dogs-must-be-carried-on-this-escalator/30290#30290), comments referring to a completed edit).

I flagged the first, then clicked the second flag button, and upon trying to flag (I am not sure if I made a reason selection) the **You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds** message appeared.

When I attempted to flag again I got a warning like **Please select a reason for flagging**. After waiting or dismissing the message and trying to flag the comment again, the "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" warning appeared again, and so on, in a circular fashion; I was not able to get the flag dialog to appear to select a reason.

I was able to successfully flag upon refreshing the page (but did not think of that at first in my confusion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this - a fix will be pushed tonight.

Comment: Thanks, @Jarrod! I've tested out rapidly flagging some chatty/obsolete comments and no longer see the issue, so it's fixed as far as I can tell :o)